# Crystal Reports - Help displaying multiple Report Fields with one Formula

Tags: crystal-reports, report, field

I am not a programmer by any means.  I am but a curious lowly administrator attempting to modify a report for my needs.  I have a Crystal Reports .rpt file that shows Purchase Orders and payments against those purchase orders.  My problem is that the payment lines don't reference the purchase order number.  Currently, I have to export the report then go through in excel and manually match each AP line to its matching Purchase Order number.  I would like the AP line to also show the Purchase Order number.

There is a field in the report called "@Voucher_PO_ID" with the following formula in it:

```
if {LAGL019Q.RECORD_TYPE} = "3" then
   if {LAGL019Q.SOURCE} = "AP" then
     {LAGL019Q.TRANS_REF_NUM}
   else if {LAGL019Q.SOURCE} = "PO" or {LAGL019Q.SOURCE} = "RQ" then
             {LAGL019Q.PO_ID}
    else " "
else " "
```

As I understand it, this formula is saying if the SOURCE is an AP (accounts payable) then for that line show the TRANS_REF_NUM (the check number for the payment), but if the SOURCE is a PO (purchase order) then show PO_ID (the purchase order number).

Again, knowing very little about programming, I was hoping it would be something as simple as modifying the if then statement to:

```
   if {LAGL019Q.SOURCE} = "AP" then
     {LAGL019Q.TRANS_REF_NUM} and {LAGL019Q.PO_ID}
```

But this does not work.  I can append some text to the end of {LAGL019Q.TRANS_REF_NUM} by adding {LAGL019Q.TRANS_REF_NUM} + "blah" so I'm not sure why it won't add another field.

It just won't let me change this part of the formula:

```
"   if {LAGL019Q.SOURCE} = "AP" then
     {LAGL019Q.TRANS_REF_NUM}"
```

If I simply try:

```
   if {LAGL019Q.SOURCE} = "AP" then
     {LAGL019Q.PO_ID}
```

It still won't work and I'm not sure why?  IF its an accounts payable line, I want it to show the corresponding PO_ID.  It just shows a blank field when I do this even though I know the AP line has a corresponding PO.

I'm guessing there is some larger thing I am unaware of regarding how the actual database is setup.  Maybe AP lines don't actually reference the PO_ID and I'm just assuming they do.

Most google searches I did brought be back here so I thought I'd post my problem.  I've searched similar questions and they are mostly out of my league.  Thanks ahead for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I think your only problem is that you're trying to use a logical operator (the `AND` keyword) instead of a string operator (The `+` or `&` characters). Hopefully it's as simple as this:

```
if {LAGL019Q.RECORD_TYPE} = "3" then
   if {LAGL019Q.SOURCE} = "AP" then
     "This is the transaction#: " + {LAGL019Q.TRANS_REF_NUM} + 
     ", and this is the PO ID: " + {LAGL019Q.PO_ID}
   else if {LAGL019Q.SOURCE} = "PO" or {LAGL019Q.SOURCE} = "RQ" then
             {LAGL019Q.PO_ID}
    else " "
else " "
```

If the {LAGL019Q.PO_ID}="AP" then this *should* result in:

`This is the transaction#: <TheActualNumber>, and this is the PO ID: <TheActualPOID>`

EDIT1: One other thought: How sure are you that the database actually holds valid PO#s for these records? If you tried to use `if {LAGL019Q.SOURCE} = "AP" then {LAGL019Q.PO_ID}` and it turned up blank, then that's a pretty good indicator that {LAGL019Q.PO_ID} is actually null for that record.

Comment: I fear you might be correct with your edit.  I tried:

   if {LAGL019Q.SOURCE} = "AP" then
     {LAGL019Q.PO_ID}

And it returned a blank.

Its just weird to me that in the database, the record for the account payable line wouldn't hold a value for its corresponding purchase order.  For example, if there is Purchase Order 123 for $5 and then a $5 payment against Purchase Order 123, the $5 payment should reference Purchase Order 123.  Its bizarre to me that in the database, it wouldn't.

Thanks for your response.

Comment: if your looking for just what is shown I would change the first line to: if {LAGL019Q.RECORD_TYPE} = "3" AND {LAGL019Q.SOURCE = "AP" THEN... you can then remove the 2nd else " " statement.  If you have this looking for more types/sources then this coding makes sense.